# How to write an if statement for an image ? I want the text in an edit to change depending on the image choose

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

If you are given  of images of every animal, in a game and are told to click on one of your choice. You click on a deer and this takes you to the next form. The next form asks you to choose between 3 images which correctly spells the opposite gender of the deer .

I want to know how to display the word deer on the second form in an edit. And how to get the word in the edit to be able to change depending on the image clicked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> how to display the word deer on the second form in an edit

Something like `Form2.Edit1.Text := 'deer';`

> how to get the word in the edit to be able to change depending on the image clicked

I would put the words in an array, and then set the `Tag` property of each image to be the corresponding index in that array.  The `Sender` parameter of the `OnClick` handler will tell you which image was clicked on, then you can read that image's `Tag` value and use it to assign the image's word from the array to the `Edit` control.